# Dynamically reduce Semaphore's capacity

Tags: c#, concurrency, thread-safety, locking, semaphore

I have been trying to use a Semaphore to control number of requests that my service can handle. I.E.

```
class Service : IDisposable {
    SemaphoreSlim s = new SemaphoreSlim(InitialCapacity);

    ....
    async void ProcessRequest() {
        await s.WaitAsync();
        try {
             ......
        } finally {
            s.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 problems I am encountering that I am not sure how to solve. I have been using similar hacks to resolve these problems, but I wonder if there is any better way

1. I want to be able to dynamically change the capacity of my service class, so I have something like this.

   ```
   void ChangeCapacity(int newCapacity) {
       int extraRequestsCount = newCapacity - oldCapacity;
       if (extraRequestsCount > 0) {
           s.Release(extraRequestsCount);
       }
       else if (extraRequestsCount < 0) {
           for (int i = 0; i < -extraRequestsCount; i++) {
               s.WaitAsync(); // try to steal some resources, over time...
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. At the dispose method, I want to make sure all the request processing completes before I dispose the semaphore, otherwise the s.Release() call in my ProcessRequest() would throw ObjectDisposedException so I did the following

   ```
   public void Dispose() {
       if (s!= null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < oldCapacity; i++) {
               s.Wait();
           }
           s.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```

Note that I have been using loop to manually wait many times. This is really slow if the capacity is large. Is there a better way to do this? There's a Release(int count) for semaphore why isn't there a Wait(int count)?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

What I'd probably do is when the adjustment is made, replace your semaphore instance with a new semaphore with the desired capacity, and assign all future work to that semaphore. The existing and now dereferenced semaphore will not be garbage collected until all threads are done referencing it, so it should be safe to do this as long as you assign the semaphore variable locally to each thread.

Comment: Thanks, but this would only solve my first problem not the second though? Also, if we are swapping out Semaphore, we need to make it volatile right? this would make the normal request slower in favor in these rarer operations... this is why I didn't do the swap out in the first place

Comment: Thought about it a bit more, it seem like even volatile is not enough. We should need to put locks around it because creating new semaphore takes time and during the creation the original semaphore state may change... so I guess this solution would not work for me at ll

Comment: You don't need to lock it. This is the concept of eager evaluation. If I assign the variable locally at the start of my method, another thread can change the original reference that I assigned from and my local variable remains the same reference. You'd want volatile here to ensure the compiler doesn't optimize the assignment. In terms of issue #2 (the spindown), you should not be calling Dispose UNTIL all of your instances are done. Consider your architecture as Dispose is for unmanaged resources, not managed business logic.